# Flutter FloatingActionButton not showing the right Icon on linux

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a simple App with flutter on linux. Below the code for the main window:

```
class EasyWalletHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const EasyWalletHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "EasyWallet",
      theme: yaru.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: yaru.darkTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: const Center(
          child: Text("No wallets yet..."),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {print("pressed!");},
          tooltip: 'Add',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the app, it shows like this:

[image]

As you see the icon of the action button is incorrect... I have tried other icons too and all are broken.

What could the problem be?

Comment: what is yaru in your code ?

Comment: A library I found here https://flutterawesome.com/a-tutorial-for-creating-an-ubuntu-linux-flutter-app/. but without it I have the same result.

Comment: share you code as much as you can, right now i can only speculate that it's somehow related to the language/locale issue

Comment: While project here: [easy_wallet](https://github.com/stefanofornari/easy_wallet) . I though as well about locale or UTF problems, but an Icon should be an image shouldn't be? thanks for looking into it

Comment: it's not necessary to have image, let me check the project. have you tried the same project ?

Comment: yes I am working on that project; it may not be necessary for a + but I'd like to understand what's broken; I'll need the icons sooner or later...